# Load products in grid serializer after CSV import through AJAX

Tags: import, csv, tabs, grid-serlization

I want to use import feature like attached screen-shot in my custom module. please refer the attached screen-shot.
[image]

Actually I want to load the products in grid which are mentioned in CSV after import the CSV in tab.

Here is the live demo to understand the question in detail http://demo-extension.magestore.com/inventory/index.php/inventoryadmin/adminhtml_supplier/edit/id/165/key/9966a1319b9d12110d856f159165ed2f/. After login navigate to Inventory > Manage Suppliers > click on row in grid > click in Products tab.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

**I have set bounty here for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515864/load-produts-in-grid-serializer-after-csv-import-through-ajax . You can answer here also to get extra benefit.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515864/load-produts-in-grid-serializer-after-csv-import-through-ajax/28602329#28602329

Comment: Hello sorry I cannot be of help to you however your question and screenshot got my attention as I am fairly new to Magento.  It appears the screenshot above is for a plugin which might allow/help with managing a store that has Drop Shipping products from other suppliars...if I am right about what the module does in the screenshot, then could you possibly share with me the name of the module so I can possibly get it or see how it works please?  Would appreciate it!

Comment: Screen-shot is from the reference site (Magestore inventory management) as i mention the link in my question. I need ajax import functionality like reference link. If you have that one module, please share with me if you can. That would be appreciated :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We do a gridreload in a module of ours. The idea is simple, just run grid.reload() once you are done. To do this you need to know which javascript object to call.

Example of the reload:
https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_SimpleBundle/blob/master/js/ho/simplebundle/product.js#L107

To get the grid object, take a look here:
https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_SimpleBundle/blob/master/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/ho/simplebundle/product/edit/upsell/config.phtml#L47